# How to say it in English "Khana nikalo"?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

I am trying to speak English but I am stuck with the following situations that I have to frequently use. I am a Hindi speaking person.
Example,

> Khana nikalo

In Indian villages we keep all the food items on a mat when the food is ready and everybody in the family sits on it and eat the food. When the food is ready and we want to eat we ask someone to take the food from kitchen and put it on the mat. We say "khana nikalo" in Hindi. What I understood from [this link explaining English idioms](https://www.smart-words.org/quotes-sayings/idioms-meaning.html), the phrase above is not an idiom. It's basically a soft command, to as someone to do something.

When I try to ask someone these questions I can't figure out how to say it in English. How the English people say when the meal is ready and they want the lunch/dinner table ready? Do they say this

> "please ready the lunch/dinner table"?

I am just confused how they do say it. What is the equivalent in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, "Would you please serve the meal," would be an approximate translation. Colloquially, an unruly child might say, "Can we eat now?"

More polite might be the use of "Is everyone ready to eat?" This might be used after some preliminary activity, such as playing a game, and it doesn't imply that someone is arbitrarily designated as server. In many cultures, it's considered impolite to assume that a person is expected to serve a meal unless that person is a paid employee.

Comment: Getting the table ready for people to eat is called _setting the table_, if that is what you meant. In Western culture, the most basic aspect of this is putting a knife and fork at each person's place.